# Add manual & print manual details - Java

Tags: java, methods, printing, addition

I am new to Java & have been working through set tasks, so far I am on a task which is asking me to:

"3. Design and implement a class named Library which can contain details of all the manuals in the library. You class should (at least) have methods to add a manual and print details of all manuals."

Already I have a "Manual" class which is as follows (Based on the first 2 tasks set):

```
public class Manual {

    String serialNumber, title, author;

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Manual man= new Manual();
        man.print();
    }

    public Manual(){
        set("??????", "Untitled", "Unknown");
    }

    public Manual(String serialNumber, String title, String author)
    {
        set(serialNumber, title, author);
    }

    public String getserialNumber()
    {
        return serialNumber;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public void set(String serialNumber, String title, String author)
    {
        this. serialNumber = serialNumber;
        this. title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("Serial Number : " +serialNumber);
        System.out.println("Title : " +title);
        System.out.println("Author : " +author);
    }

    public void print(String heading)
    {
        System.out.println(heading);
        print();
    }

    public void ask()
    {
        serialNumber = Console.askString("Please enter the serial number: ");
        title = Console.askString("Please enter the title: ");
        author = Console.askString("Please enter the author: ");
        set(serialNumber, title, author);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "SerialNumber: " + serialNumber +"\n"
               +"Title: " + title + "\n" 
               +"Author: " + author +"\n";
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(this.toString());

    }
}
```

And next, is the library class which I have attempted to complete correctly:

```
public class Library {

    public void print(String header){
        Manual.print(header);   }

    public void ask(String prompt) {
        Manual.ask(prompt);

}
}
```

Have I managed to complete this question adequately based on what is present in my library class? I would much appreciate it if anyone could educate me on wether there are any errors present or if I am missing sections of code in order for me to complete the task.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my logical way, think it'd have been better in this ways

/// Library Class

```
import java.util.*;



public class Library 
{


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

String serialNumber, title, author;


Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Please enter the serial number: ");
serialNumber = input.next();

System.out.print("Please enter the title: ");
title= input.next();

System.out.print("Please enter the author: ");
author = input.next();

Manual man= new Manual(serialNumber,title,author);

man.print();


}


}
```

/// Manual Class

```
public class Manual 
{
String serialNumber, title, author;


public Manual(String serialNumber, String title, String author)
{
setSerialNumber(serialNumber);
setTitle(title);
setAuthor(author);
}

//// serial number

public void setSerialNumber(String number)
{
serialNumber = number;
}


public String getserialNumber()
{
return serialNumber;
}

public void setTitle(String mytitle)
{
    title = mytitle;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setAuthor(String myAuthor)
{
author = myAuthor;
}
public String getAuthor()
{
return author;
}

public void print()
{
System.out.println("Serial Number : " +serialNumber);
System.out.println("Title : " +title);
System.out.println("Author : " +author);
}

public void print(String heading)
{
System.out.println(heading);
printing();
}


public String toString()
{
return "SerialNumber: " + serialNumber +"\n"
+"Title: " + title + "\n" 
+"Author: " + author +"\n";
}

public void printing()
{
System.out.println(this.toString());

}
}
```

and as an advice, always do simple things, simple but logical code. i'm also a beginner like you. that's what i've always been told

hope it was helpful